# Animate svg with @keyframes on an elipsis path

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, keyframe

As the title says, I'm trying to animate a svg across what would look like an ellipsis path to match that
of the first icon(infinity symbol). I've tried using transform but the movement is awful. How could I achieve this in a smooth(as it can be) way?

I've found some articles about something similar but it doesn't get me the smooth ellipsis I'm after:
https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/
http://thenewcode.com/860/Animating-Elements-In-Arcs-Circles-and-Ellipses-With-CSS
https://usefulangle.com/post/32/moving-an-element-in-circular-path-with-css

Here is a link to a pen https://codepen.io/acubaniti/pen/abNqzEV?editors=1100

Here is the code :

```css
#gesture {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#phone {
  fill: white;
  animation: phone-orbits-cw 6s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.38, 0.1) infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center top;
}

#left, #right {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: white;
  transform-origin: 200px 150px;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 314;
  stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  opacity: 0;
}

#right {
  animation: circle-fill 6s linear infinite;
  stroke: white;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

#left {
  animation: circle-fill-left 6s linear infinite;
  stroke: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

@keyframes circle-fill {
  0%, 12.5% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 314;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  12.5%, 100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  49%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes circle-fill-left {
  12.5% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 314;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  49%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes phone-orbits-cw {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -360deg) translate3d(2%, -5%, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
  }
  58.75% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -360deg) translate3d(2%, -5%, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
  }
  72.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  86.25% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg) translate3d(-2%, -5%, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -360deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -360deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes phone-orbits-ccw {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -180deg);
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -180deg) translate3d(2%, -5%, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg);
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body style="background-color: black;"> 
    <svg id="gesture" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
      <g id="phone">
        <path  d="M212.1 23.1H90.2c-4.8 0-8.8 3.9-8.8 8.8v236.4c0 4.8 3.9 8.8 8.8 8.8h121.9c4.8 0 8.8-3.9 8.8-8.8V31.8c0-4.8-4-8.7-8.8-8.7zm0 8.5c.1 0 .2.1.2.2v28.4H90.2V31.6h121.9zM90 268.2l.2-200.6h122.1l-.2 200.8-122.1-.2z"/>
        <circle cx="151.1" cy="248.2" r="8.8"/>
        <path d="M142 49.5h18.3c2.3 0 4.1-1.8 4.1-4.1s-1.8-4.1-4.1-4.1H142c-2.3 0-4.1 1.8-4.1 4.1s1.8 4.1 4.1 4.1z"/>
      </g>
      <circle id="right" cx="200" cy="150" r="50"/>
      <circle id="left" cx="100" cy="150" r="50"/>
    </svg> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Stack Snippets do not support SCSS. Please post compiled CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can compromise on browser compatibility, you should be able to do this in a much more semantic way using a [motion path](https://www.w3.org/TR/motion-1). It needs Chrome 64, Edge 79, Firefox 72, Opera 45, but has no Safari support.

The following example simplifies your code in several ways. First, I have rewritten the two circles as a single path, and additionally moved it so that the start and end of the path (the mid-point of the "infinity" sign) is at the origin of the coordinate system. This is because this path will be reused as the motion path - not by quotation, that is unfortunately impossible if you stay with CSS, but so you can just copy-and-paste the path commands.

To make my life a bit easier with the `stroke-dashoffset` animation, the path also gets the attribute (not CSS property!) `pathLength="100"`. This is basically an arbitrary value that means: for all distance-along-a-path computaions, act *as if* 100 was the path length.

Second, I defined an `offset-path` with the same path commands used. `offset-rotate` is set to `0deg` to avoid the phone rotating along the path tangent while it moves. The `offset-distance` increases from 0 to 100% during the animation.

```css
#gesture {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#phone {
  fill: white;
  animation: phone-orbit 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  offset-path: path("M0 0 A 30 30 0 0 1 60 0 A 30 30 0 0 1 0 0 A 30 30 0 0 0 -60 0 A 30 30 0 0 0 0 0");
  offset-rotate: 0deg;
  offset-distance: 0;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}

#infinity {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 6.666;
  stroke: white;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: infinity-fill 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes infinity-fill {
  0%, 25% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25%, 100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  49%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes phone-orbit {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: black;"> 
    <svg id="gesture" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
      <g id="phone">
        <path  d="M212.1 23.1H90.2c-4.8 0-8.8 3.9-8.8 8.8v236.4c0 4.8 3.9 8.8 8.8 8.8h121.9c4.8 0 8.8-3.9 8.8-8.8V31.8c0-4.8-4-8.7-8.8-8.7zm0 8.5c.1 0 .2.1.2.2v28.4H90.2V31.6h121.9zM90 268.2l.2-200.6h122.1l-.2 200.8-122.1-.2z"/>
        <circle cx="151.1" cy="248.2" r="8.8"/>
        <path d="M142 49.5h18.3c2.3 0 4.1-1.8 4.1-4.1s-1.8-4.1-4.1-4.1H142c-2.3 0-4.1 1.8-4.1 4.1s1.8 4.1 4.1 4.1z"/>
      </g>
      <path id="infinity" transform="translate(150 150) scale(1.666)" d="M0 0 A 30 30 0 0 1 60 0 A 30 30 0 0 1 0 0 A 30 30 0 0 0 -60 0 A 30 30 0 0 0 0 0"  pathLength="100"/>
    </svg> 
</body>
```

For better support, you can switch over to a in-markup [SMIL animation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html). Only old IE versions will fail you there.

The difference is mostly in the way the different animations are started: apart from the first `infinityFill` animation being started at 0s, each subsequent animation is started in relation to its runtimes. Especially the `phoneOrbit` animation starts at the end of the `infinityFill` animation, then the end of `phoneOrbit` starts `infinityFill` again, and so on in infinity.

Additionally, the motion path can be truely reused.

```css
#gesture {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#phone {
  fill: white;
  opacity: 0;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}

#infinity {
  fill: none;
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-dasharray: 100;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: black;"> 
    <svg id="gesture" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <defs>
        <path id="motion" d="M0 0 A 30 30 0 0 1 60 0 A 30 30 0 0 1 0 0 A 30 30 0 0 0 -60 0 A 30 30 0 0 0 0 0"  pathLength="100"/>
      </defs>
      <g id="phone">
        <path  d="M212.1 23.1H90.2c-4.8 0-8.8 3.9-8.8 8.8v236.4c0 4.8 3.9 8.8 8.8 8.8h121.9c4.8 0 8.8-3.9 8.8-8.8V31.8c0-4.8-4-8.7-8.8-8.7zm0 8.5c.1 0 .2.1.2.2v28.4H90.2V31.6h121.9zM90 268.2l.2-200.6h122.1l-.2 200.8-122.1-.2z"/>
        <circle cx="151.1" cy="248.2" r="8.8"/>
        <path d="M142 49.5h18.3c2.3 0 4.1-1.8 4.1-4.1s-1.8-4.1-4.1-4.1H142c-2.3 0-4.1 1.8-4.1 4.1s1.8 4.1 4.1 4.1z"/>
        <animateMotion id="phoneOrbit" dur="3s"
                       begin="infinityFill.end" rotate="0">
          <mpath href="#motion" />
        </animateMotion>
        <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="6s"
                 begin="infinityFill.begin"
                 values="0;0;1;1" keyTimes="0;.45;.5;1" />
      </g>
      <use id="infinity" href="#motion" transform="translate(150 150) scale(1.666)">
        <animate id="infinityFill" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
                 dur="3s" begin="0s;phoneOrbit.end"
                 values="100;0;0" keyTimes="0;.5;1" />
        <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="3s"
                 begin="infinityFill.begin"
                 values="1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.75;1" />
      </use>
    </svg> 
</body>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you a lot!